# crystal reports sum only last item in detail

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I wish to display in the group footer the sum of the sold qty column (which is easily done) and then only the last value of the on hand qty column.

I think a variable can do this, but not sure how to do it as I'm new to Crystal and its variables.

Here is an example

```
            Sold qty    On Hand Qty
details         1           5
                2           3
============================================
GF Total        3           3
============================================
details         6           10
                3           7
============================================
GF Total        9           7
```

Comment: Did you try to put the field `{yourTable.OnHandQty}` in the group-footer? This should show the last detail value.

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks MatSnow. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Put the field `{yourTable.OnHandQty}` in the group-footer.

This will show the last detail value and will work as long as there's no suppression on details.

**Note:** The "last record" is determined by the sort within the group. This means that if the sorting is changed, the wrong value will be displayed.

Comment: There is one drawback to this approach.  You can't sort your data.  This approach will always return the OnHandQty for the last record that printed.  If the sort of data changes the order in such a way that the last record printed has the wrong OnHandQty, then you will have the wrong value in the footer section.

Comment: Very good point. I am actually sorting by date which means the most recent sales date should always be the last record.

Comment: @R.McMillan That's correct. I've edited the answer and added a note.

Answer (score 0):

Yes !! You can do this using variables.

**Step 1: Create a Formula Field Named as OnHand**

**OnHand** 
shared numbervar OnHand;
Onhand :=  (Your Table Field) + Onhand +;

- Place this one in Details section and suppress it (Right Click
  Formula --> Format Field --> Common --> Supress)

**Step 2 : Create one more formula to display the result**

**PrintOnHand**
shared numbervar OnHand;
OnHand;

- Place this formula in Group Footer

**Step 3 : Create one more formula Clear**

**Clear**
shared numbervar OnHand;
OnHand :=0;

- Place this formula in group Header and suppress it. (This is to clear the Onhand
  Value for every records or group).